# MySQL Client Connection Has Delay When Connecting via SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl

I am having a problem with various clients for MySQL where the speed for connecting to a database is dramatically lower than I'd like.  Basically I have a Python script running MySQLdb that connects with cient SSL certificates then inserts one row into the database and quits.  That being said, even the `mysql` command is experiencing this delay.

The problem is, it takes about 2.4 seconds to complete a single SSL connection.  Normally I wouldn't care, but I have been reading posts by people saying that the addition of SSL should be negligible in terms of speed.  If this is possible, I would definitely need it.

Server is running Solaris 10 on x86 using packages off of [MySQL.com](http://mysql.com/).  There are 2 relevant zones, one has MySQL server, the other is running the client.  Connection is made over TCP.

MySQL client version:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for solaris10 (i386) using readline 5.1

MySQL server version:

> mysqld  Ver 5.5.27 for solaris10 on i386 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

Two test GRANTs:

> mysql> GRANT SELECT ON wdia_user_scheduler.command TO 'jojo'@'l5-cisswdia.IRRELEVANT_REMOVED';
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> GRANT SELECT ON wdia_user_scheduler.command
>       -> TO 'jaja'@'l5-cisswdia.IRRELEVANT_REMOVED'
>       -> REQUIRE SUBJECT
>       -> 'IRRELEVANT_REMOVED'
>       -> AND ISSUER 'IRRELEVANT_REMOVED'
>       -> AND CIPHER 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA';
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Two test connections using client software:

> bscable@l5-cisswdia:~/mysql$ time mysql -u jojo -h jobs.example.com -e exit
>
> 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.010 total
>
> bscable@l5-cisswdia:~/mysql$ time mysql -u jaja --ssl --ssl-key=ssl/bscable-key.pem --ssl-cert=ssl/bscable-cert.pem -h jobs.example.com -e exit
>
> 1.22s user 0.00s system 50% cpu 2.421 total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was using 4096-bit keys on the SSL certs.  Going down to 1024-bit solved the speed issue.